# The PHP static methods is Deprecated or not?

Tags: php

Warning:

> In PHP 7, calling non-static methods statically is deprecated, and will generate an E_DEPRECATED warning.
>   Support for calling non-static methods statically may be removed in the future.

I run in PHP 7 this:

```
public static function loadStandards() {
   return true;
}
```

Or this:

```
static public function loadStandards() {
   return true;
}
```

And is working fine no **E_DEPRECATED** warning from PHP.

So.. Is deprecated? or not?

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Tools;

use App\Http\Controllers\Central;

class ShopTool extends Central
{
    public static $loaded = [];

    public static function loadStandards()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Static functions are not deprecated. Calling _non-static_ methods as if they were static is deprecated.

Comment: Show us your `class` please.

Comment: Please you can write some code to understand what is the non-static?

Comment: @user3211908 "non-static" means it doesn't have the `static` option. Plain English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static functions are just fine, not deprecated at all.

```
class foo {
    public static function myStaticFunction() {
        echo "I'm declared static! Calling me statically works great.";
    }
}
```

You can call `foo::myStaticFunction()` and it'll work just fine.

It used to be that you could call a non-static function statically. This is what PHP is deprecating.

For example:

```
class foo {
    public function myNonStaticFunction() {
        echo "I'm not declared static, if you try to call me statically you'll get a deprecated warning";
    }
}
```

Now if you try to call `foo::myNonStaticFunction()` as if it were static, PHP will give you a deprecated warning.

See here for a working example: https://3v4l.org/lXYsf

Comment: I just updated my answer. The second code example is a non static function, and I'm showing you how calling it statically will get the deprecated warning. Did you look at the link I provided as well?

Comment: Ok so, the static never deprecated in the future? Like my code above?

Comment: Correct. So long as you declare a function to be static, you can call it statically. It is not being deprecated.